# Как в метод .includes() по очереди подставлять элементы другого массива

Tags: javascript

Дано 2 массива.

Элементы первого массива филтруются при помощи метода .filter() Вторым массивом.

Таким образом надо, чтобы в метод filter было условие, равен ли элемент перового массива элементу 2 массива.

Как в метод .includes() по очереди подставлять элементы другого массива

```
   let filterBY = ["@gmail", "@mail", "@yandex"];

let initatEmails = [
    "user1@gmail.com",
    "user2@rambler.com",
    "user3@torbox.com",
    "user4@mail.com",
    "user5@yandex.ru",
];
```

Как вывести новый массив, который отфильтрует массива initalEmails по filterBY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = [5,6,'3',1,2];
const arr2 = [1,2,'3'];
const arr3 = arr1.filter((x) => arr2.includes(x));

console.log(arr3)
```

---

```js
let filterBy = ["@gmail", "@mail", "@yandex"];

let initatEmails = [
    "user1@gmail.com",
    "user2@rambler.com",
    "user3@torbox.com",
    "user4@mail.com",
    "user5@yandex.ru",
];

const arr3 = initatEmails.filter((x) => filterBy.some((f) => x.includes(f)));

console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: а если по отрывку элемента? я дополнил вопрос

Comment: @AndrewWander дополнил

Comment: спасибо большое!